# ChipGroup single selection

Tags: android, material-components, material-components-android, android-chips

How can I force a `ChipGroup` to act like a `RadioGroup` as in having at least one selected item always? Setting `setSingleSelection(true)` also adds the possibility to have nothing selected if you click twice on a `Chip`.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

To prevent all chips from being deselected you can use the method **`setSelectionRequired`**:

```
chipGroup.setSelectionRequired(true)
```

You can also define it in the layout using the **`app:selectionRequired`** attribute:

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
    app:singleSelection="true"
    app:selectionRequired="true"
    app:checkedChip="@id/..."
    ..>
```

**Note:** This requires a minimum of version **1.2.0**

Comment: This needs to get upvotes. The functionality no longer needs to be hacked like with the other answers.

Answer (score 24):

## EDIT

With version `1.2.0-alpha02` the *old* hacky solution is no longer required!

Either use the attribute `app:selectionRequired="true"`

```xml
<com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
            android:id="@+id/group"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:selectionRequired="true"
            app:singleSelection="true">

  (...)
</com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>
```

Or in code

```
// Kotlin
group.isSelectionRequired = true

// Java
group.setSelectionRequired(true);
```

---

#### For older versions

There are two steps to achieve this

### Step 1

We have this support built-in, just make sure to add `app:singleSelection="true"` to your `ChipGroup`, for example:

**XML**

```xml
<com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
            android:id="@+id/group"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:singleSelection="true">

        <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                android:id="@+id/option_1"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Option 1" />

        <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                android:id="@+id/option_2"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Option 2" />
</com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>
```

**Code**

```
// Kotlin
group.isSingleSelection = true

// Java
group.setSingleSelection(true);
```

### Step 2

Now to support a radio group like functionality:

```
var lastCheckedId = View.NO_ID
chipGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener { group, checkedId ->
    if(checkedId == View.NO_ID) {
        // User tried to uncheck, make sure to keep the chip checked          
        group.check(lastCheckedId)
        return@setOnCheckedChangeListener
    }
    lastCheckedId = checkedId

    // New selection happened, do your logic here.
    (...)

}
```

From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/chip/ChipGroup):

> ChipGroup also supports a multiple-exclusion scope for a set of chips.
>   When you set the app:singleSelection attribute, checking one chip that
>   belongs to a chip group unchecks any previously checked chip within
>   the same group. The behavior mirrors that of RadioGroup.

Comment: The OP asked for a way to ensure that at least one Chip is always selected. This answer points to functionality they were already aware of in their question, and doesn't meet their needs.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out but downvoting seems a bit excessive, I've added the working solution now.

Comment: Fair enough, now that there's a working solution I'll remove the downvote. :)

You still have a typo in `group.check(lastCheckId)` though.

Comment: Also, now that I think about it, doesn't calling `group.check()` cause this listener to be called again, redundantly? It's only one extra call, due to some guard code in `ChipGroup`, but still.

Comment: @JoaquimLey could you explain what is the return type `return@setOnCheckedChangeListener`.

Comment: @AgapitoGallartiBernat it should be void/Unit, the `@ setOnCheckedChangeListener ` is a Kotlin syntax, which refers to what statement you want to return at, in this case, the logic running for the listener lambda.

Answer (score 14):

A solution would be to preset a clicked chip and then toggling the clickable property of the chips:

```
chipGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener((chipGroup, id) -> {
    Chip chip = ((Chip) chipGroup.getChildAt(chipGroup.getCheckedChipId()));
    if (chip != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < chipGroup.getChildCount(); ++i) {
            chipGroup.getChildAt(i).setClickable(true);
        }
        chip.setClickable(false);
    }
});
```

Comment: There's a slight error in this code. chipGroup.getChildAt() takes an index, not the resource id of the chip view.

Comment: @ToddDeLand: That's right. I forgot to mention that in my use case I added Chips to a ChipGroup programmatically according to some other container so resource ids weren't helpful. I used chip.setId(i++) before adding them to the group.

Comment: As weird as it sounds this is so far the only solution I found too (with correction of using id not indexes).

Comment: Chip chip = chipGroup.findViewById(chipGroup.getCheckedChipId());

Comment: The only problem that I found is when I start the screen with a chip initially selected through XML. If you click it, it will deselect. After that, this solution works

Comment: hipGroup.getChildAt() takes an index. you most use  Joseph code  Chip chip = chipGroup.findViewById(chipGroup.getCheckedChipId());

Answer (score 6):

Brief modification of @adriennoir 's answer (in Kotlin). Thanks for the help!
Note that `getChildAt()` takes an index.

```
for (i in 0 until group.childCount) {
    val chip = group.getChildAt(i)
    chip.isClickable = chip.id != group.checkedChipId
}
```

Here's my larger `setOnCheckedChangeListener, for context:

```
intervalChipGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener { group, checkedId ->

    for (i in 0 until group.childCount) {
        val chip = group.getChildAt(i)
        chip.isClickable = chip.id != group.checkedChipId
    }

    when (checkedId) {
        R.id.intervalWeek -> {
            view.findViewById<Chip>(R.id.intervalWeek).chipStrokeWidth = 1F
            view.findViewById<Chip>(R.id.intervalMonth).chipStrokeWidth = 0F
            view.findViewById<Chip>(R.id.intervalYear).chipStrokeWidth = 0F
            currentIntervalSelected = weekInterval
            populateGraph(weekInterval)
        }
        R.id.intervalMonth -> {
            view.findViewById<Chip>(R.id.intervalWeek).chipStrokeWidth = 0F
            view.findViewById<Chip>(R.id.intervalMonth).chipStrokeWidth = 1F
            view.findViewById<Chip>(R.id.intervalYear).chipStrokeWidth = 0F
            currentIntervalSelected = monthInterval
            populateGraph(monthInterval)

        }
        R.id.intervalYear -> {
            view.findViewById<Chip>(R.id.intervalWeek).chipStrokeWidth = 0F
            view.findViewById<Chip>(R.id.intervalMonth).chipStrokeWidth = 0F
            view.findViewById<Chip>(R.id.intervalYear).chipStrokeWidth = 1F
            currentIntervalSelected = yearInterval
            populateGraph(yearInterval)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Most of the answers are great and really helpful for me. Another slight modification to @adriennoir and @Todd DeLand, to prevent unchecking already checked chip in a `setSingleSelection(true)` ChipGroup, here's my solution:

```
for (i in 0 until chipGroup.childCount) {
    val chip = chipGroup.getChildAt(i) as Chip
    chip.isCheckable = chip.id != chipGroup.checkedChipId
    chip.isChecked = chip.id == chipGroup.checkedChipId
}
```

For me, I just need to prevent the same checked Chip to be unchecked without making it non-clickable. This way, the user can still click the checked chip and see the fancy ripple effect and nothing will happen.

Answer (score 2):

If **singleSelection** doesn't work with added dynamically chips, you must ***generate id*** for each chip when create them and then add to **ChipGroup**.

```
val chip = inflater.inflate(
R.layout.item_crypto_currency_category_chip,
binding.chipGroupCryptoCurrencyCategory,
false) as Chip

chip.id = ViewCompat.generateViewId()

binding.chipGroupCryptoCurrencyCategory.addView(chip)

//Set default value with index 0 when ChipGroup created.
if (index == 0) binding.chipGroupCryptoCurrencyCategory.check(chip.id)
```

**item_crypto_currency_category_chip.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.chip.Chip xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/chip_smart_contract"
style="@style/Widget.Signal.Chip"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**item_crypto_currency_tag_category.xml**

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_6x"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
        android:id="@+id/chip_group_crypto_currency_category"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:singleSelection="true"
        app:singleLine="true"
        />

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

**Result:**

[image: ChipGroup example]

Comment: I am doing the same but still, multiple chips are being selected. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it:

```
var previousSelection: Int = default_selection_id 
chipGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener { chipGroup, id ->
    if (id == -1) //nothing is selected.
        chipGroup.check(previousSelection)
    else
        previousSelection = id
```

Comment: Doesn't this cause the previously clicked Chip to be checked each time, rather than the one the user actually clicked?

Comment: No, when The user clicks a chip, the chip group updates the selection automatically. All this code does is that it stores the most recent selection in case there was no item being currently selected, as chipgroup allows that.

Comment: The only thing I would highlight then is that, as with Joaquim's answer, this involves a single duplicate call to `onCheckedChange()` by calling `chipGroup.check()`.

Comment: Yeah I believe my answer was the simplest of all. But no one noticed it. 

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me, specially because there was a default value when the screen was rendered.

Answer (score 0):

This is my working solution

```
mChipGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener((group, checkedId) -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < mChipGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
                Chip chip = (Chip) mChipGroup.getChildAt(i);
                if (chip != null) {
                    chip.setClickable(!(chip.getId() == mChipGroup.getCheckedChipId()));
                }
            }
    });
```