# How to create a set of linked buttons in android studio?

Tags: android

[image: Button group]

How would I create a set of three linked buttons that only allow one button to be selected and highlighted at a time? When button two is selected button one would become unhighlighted and button two would become highlighted

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Radio Button and Radio Group in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65987623/radio-button-and-radio-group-in-android)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [**`MaterialButtonToggleGroup`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Button.md#toggle-button) provided by the material components library.

Use the **`android:orientation="vertical"`** to have a vertical orientation and the **`singleSelection="true"`** attribute to have a single selection as described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53155035/chipgroup-single-selection).

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
    android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:singleSelection="true"
    app:selectionRequired="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 1"
        />
    <Button
        style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 2"
        />
    <Button
        style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 3"
        />
</com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

easy just use material button library
read this doc
[material button](https://material.io/components/buttons/android)